make groups by a dictionary in R
I have the task of identifying the group to which a sentence belongs according to the use of specific words, for example identifying which color has been used to describe an animal. I have a dictionary of the words I want to identify in this way:
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), pets = c("brown dog", "black cat", "orange cat", "black bird", "white hamster"))

dictionary <- c("black", "orange", "white", "brown", "green", "red")

I need to match the pets with the dictionary indicating which categories they are, to my final df be like:
final_df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), 
pets = c("brown dog", "black cat", "orange cat", "black bird", "white hamster"), 
color = c("brown", "black", "orange", "black", "white"))


Using the stringr package:
library(stringr)

regex <- str_c("\\b", dictionary, "\\b", collapse = "|")
df$color <- str_extract(df$pets, regex)
# "brown"  "black"  "orange" "black"  "white" 

In base R:
regex <- paste0(".*(", paste0("\\b", dictionary, "\\b", collapse = "|"), ").*")

df$color <- sub(regex, "\\1", df$pets)
# "brown"  "black"  "orange" "black"  "white" 


Both these solutions do the same thing. First construct a regular expression pattern match using dictionary. This regular expression will capture any of the complete words: black, orange, etc.
Due to the use of word boundaries (e.g. \\b) this pattern match will only match these words. For example, if you had white-tailed deer, this would not extract "white".
If there are multiple colors in the same string (e.g. "black white bear") then I would recommend using str_extract_all().

Those word boundaries are nice. It looks weird when you print the regex, but it works nicely. And of course, you can wrap the str_extract part in mutate() to immediately create your final_df

A base R option:
df$color <- Reduce(
  \(x, y) ifelse(grepl(pattern = y, x = df$pets, fixed = TRUE), y, x),
  dictionary, 
  init=NA_character_
)

#   id          pets  color
# 1  1     brown dog  brown
# 2  2     black cat  black
# 3  3    orange cat orange
# 4  4    black bird  black
# 5  5 white hamster  white

Same pattern using a loop:
df$color <- NA_character_
for (y in dictionary) {
  df$color <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = y, x = df$pets, fixed = TRUE), y, df$color) 
}

